# Minimizing the number of distinct elements by picking one set from each set of sets

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-hard

I have a problem as follows. Given a set of sets $U = \{S_1, S_2, … S_N\}$ where $S_i = \{s_1, s_2, ... s_m\}$. Each $s_j \in S_i$ contains a set of distinct elements. I need to pick one $s_j \in S_i$ to form $N$ sets in total such that $|\bigcup_{j=1}^N s_j|$ is **minimized**.

Is there an efficient algorithm to solve this problem. I feel that this problem is $NP-hard$ as it is somewhat similar to the *maximum coverage problem*. I have yet to be able to formally prove this intuition by reduction from the maximum coverage problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is NP-hard by a reduction from the (decision version of the) hitting set problem.
Given a set $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ of elements, a collection $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_h$ of subsets of $X$, and an integer $k$, is there a subset $X'$ of at most $k$ elements from $X$ such that $A' \cap A_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i=1, \dots, h$?

To reduce an instance of hitting set to an instance of your problem you can choose $N=h$ and $S_i = \{ \{ a  \} \mid a \in  A_i \}$.

If there is a hitting set $A'$ of size at most $k$, then each set $S_i$ contains at least one set $\{a\}$ for some $a \in A'$. Choosing one such set per $S_i$ yields a solution to your problem of size at most $k$.

If there is a solution to your problem of size at most $k$, then the union of the selected sets contains at least one element in each $A_i$ (since the sets in $S_i$ contain only elements in $A_i$), i.e., it is a hitting set.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What if $S_i$ contained sets with more than one element each ? the hitting set problem never reduces to such instances.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. If instances in which each set in $S_i$ can have a single element are valid for your problem then the reduction is valid. A reduction $f$ from $A$ to $B$ does not need to generate all instances of $B$ (think of it this way: if you have an algorithm for $B$ you can use it to solve all instances $x\in A$ by solving $f(x)\in B$). If such instances are not valid for your problem then you can modify the above reduction by adding a **common** new element $x$ to **all** sets (the size of all sets becomes $2$ and the size of the solution increases by $1$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Got it that the reduction does not need to reduce to all instances